# Collection operator for summing a NSDictionary's values

Tags: nspredicate

Is there a simple way using KVO and collection operators, that I can sum the total value of a NSDictionary like `{ ID: NSNumber }`?

Example:

```
@{
  "my_ID_abcd": @(8),
  "my_ID_efgh": @(2),
  "my_ID_ijkl": @(3)
}
```

Would give 13 as a result.

Indeed `@count` doesn't return what I want, and `@sum` doesn't work here.. `allValues.@sum.self` neither...

I need to check the sum in a NSPredicate...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of some data and the result?

Comment: @Willeke I've just edited the question

Comment: `NSPredicate` is of no use if you have one dictionary.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Using Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html) in Key-Value Coding Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks but I've already checked that and didn't find my answer :( NSPredicate is for dynamically comparing the result with another expression

Comment: `[dictionary valueForKey:@"allValues"]` doesn't work. Can't you use a predicate with a block?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that would be to use a `SUBQUERY(,,)` & `FUNCTION(,)`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"my_ID_abcd": @(8),
                        @"my_ID_efgh": @(2),
                        @"my_ID_ijkl": @(3)};
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(FUNCTION(SELF, 'allValues'), $idsValues, $idsValues = $idsValues).@sum.integerValue = %d", value];

BOOL pass = [predicate evaluateWithObject:dict];
```

From what I tried, you can't really chain two operators (ie `@sum` & `@allValues`, so I used a `SUBQUERY`:

```
SUBQUERY(allValues, $idsAllValues, $idsAllValues = $idsAllValues)
```

Since, you need a "true/false" on the last one, I used a simple comparaison against itself.

And I used `FUNCTION` to build the array of values.

That way, in the end, I can call `@sum` on it.

I'm not very familiar with `SUBQUERY` & `FUNCTION`, maybe the call could be simplified.

If you could use `predicateWithBlock:`, it would be much simpler though:

```
NSPredicate *withBlock = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    NSInteger sum = [[[evaluatedObject allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] integerValue];
    return sum == value;
}];
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this amazing suggestion! Indeed that would be much easier by hard coding.. That's a very long predicate to do not so much, I think I will have either to subclass NSDictionary to accept custom operators (@sum) or using method swizzling to do that.. :(